# Proving $E(XE(Y ))=E(X)E(Y )$

Tags: probability, statistics, expectation

Why is $E(XE(Y))=E(X)E(Y)$ where $X$ and $Y$ are random variables

I have not found any rule that can solve this.

Comment: $E(aX) = aE(X),$ for a constant $a$. But $E(Y)$ is a constant.

Answer (score 4):

$E(Y)$ is a constant with respect to $X$; you're using the linearity of expectation.

Comment: $E(Y)$ is a constant, full stop, not just with respect to $X$.

Comment: Fair enough.$ {} $

Answer (score 1):

$E(X\underbrace{E(Y)}_{\alpha}) = E(\alpha X) = \alpha E(X) = E(X) E(Y) $